# How to install prometheus exporter plugin to openSearch in helm managed environment

Tags: kubernetes, plugins, kubernetes-helm, metrics, opensearch

I want to collect metrics from my  opensearch

I've found this plugin https://github.com/aiven/prometheus-exporter-plugin-for-opensearch

but I have no idea how to connect it to my opensearch:

My current definition looks like this:

**chart.yaml:**

```
  - name: opensearch
    version: 1.8.0
    repository: https://opensearch-project.github.io/helm-charts/
```

**values.yaml:**

```
opensearch:
  plugins:
    enabled: true
    installList:
      - what should I write here ?

  addIndexedAt: true
  clusterName: ...
  masterService:...
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1000Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 3000m
      memory: 2000Mi
  config:
    opensearch.yml: ...
```

Could you please help me how to connetc plugin to opensearch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- what should I write here ?`

Try specify the plugin download URL:

```
...
installList:
- "https://github.com/aiven/prometheus-exporter-plugin-for-opensearch/releases/download/2.1.0.0/prometheus-exporter-2.1.0.0.zip"
...
```

The url you passed gets to [here](https://github.com/opensearch-project/helm-charts/blob/eeb0ae026694fbedba686b5f8e5ea0dea31d93b2/charts/opensearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L297) for installation.

Comment: Do I have to do anything in addition ? register any service monitors ?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://github.com/aiven/prometheus-exporter-plugin-for-opensearch#configure-the-prometheus-target).

Comment: Sorry, but full text searcg by word "monitor" doesn't give me any result

Comment: Why "search by word monitor" related to plugin installation and configure for scrape?

Comment: Because it is reply to my first commentary.

Comment: You need to configure your Prometheus to scrape the plugin endpoint as pointed out in the comment. Start another question if you are not familiar with how to configure Prometheus.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I am novice in such things. In my (short) experience some software responsible for metrics export provides internal service monitor configurable by values.yaml but I don't see it. In our architecture we use service monitors to let prometheus know about metrics

Comment: Opensearch as of now does not expose metrics in Prometheus format thus you will not find such settings in the values.yaml. You are probably referring to Prometheus operator ServiceMonitor; you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991038/how-to-create-a-servicemonitor-for-prometheus-operator) how to create one. For now you should be able to do `curl http(s)://<opensearch pod IP>:9200/_prometheus/metrics` to check if the plugin is working as expected.

Comment: yes, /_prometheus/metrics works. Marked as resolved