# Nginx metrics not appearing on prometheus

Tags: nginx, prometheus, microk8s

I have a single node kubernetes cluster deployed by microk8s.
I'm using the default Nginx ingress controller and the prometheus addon.
I'm trying to collect the nginx metrics on prometheus so that I monitor it later on grafana.
The problem is that I'm not getting the metrics on Prometheus after creating the serviceMonitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: kube-prom-stack-nginx-ingress-microk8s
  namespace: observability
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: kube-prom-stack
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: observability
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prom-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-ingress-microk8s
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: nginx-ingress-microk8s
    release: kube-prom-stack
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      microk8s-application: nginx-ingress-microk8s
  endpoints:
    - honorLabels: true
      enableHttp2: true
      port: health
      path: /metrics
      interval: 5s
      scheme: http
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - ingress
      - observability
      - kube-system
      - default
```

Prometheus seems to detect the scrape pool but **can't find any endpoint associated with it**.

[image: prometheus targets]

Nginx seems to be exporting the metrics correctly.
[image: Nginx metrics]

The serviceMonitor seems to have the following prometheus job:

```
- job_name: serviceMonitor/observability/kube-prom-stack-nginx-ingress-microk8s/0
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_microk8s_application, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_microk8s_application]
    separator: ;
    regex: (nginx-ingress-microk8s);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: health
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_phase]
    separator: ;
    regex: (Failed|Succeeded)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: health
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - ingress
      - observability
      - kube-system
      - default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that when deploying the Nginx ingress controller, microk8s doesn't create a service associated to it.
I had to do it manually so that it could be discovered by the prometheus ServiceMonitor.
Here is the created service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-prom-stack-nginx-ingress-microk8s
  namespace: ingress
  labels:
    microk8s-application: nginx-ingress-microk8s
    release: kube-prom-stack
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 10254
      targetPort: 10254
      name: prometheus
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    microk8s-application: nginx-ingress-microk8s
```

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI - your prometheus service discovery is using a role of endpoints. if you chance this to pod you wont need the service

Answer (score 0):

As to your `ServiceMonitor`'s definition, check the following 3 parts for your `Nginx ingress controller` service(endpoints):

1. Is it in the namespaces listed below?

```
  - ingress
  - observability
  - kube-system
  - default
```

2. Is it labelld with the following label?

```
  microk8s-application: nginx-ingress-microk8s
```

3. Does the following port name exist in its yaml definition?

```
  port: health
```

Comment: 1- Yes, it is in the "ingress" namespace. 2- yes it has the corresponding label. 3- yes it has he corresponding port.

Comment: @FrenchTechLead which port number is your svc's **health** port?

Comment: @FrenchTechLead Another possible reason might be: the Prometheus server doesnot have the appropriate Role and RoleBinding persmissions to be able to discover targets from the "ingress" namespace. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218648/3781502)

Comment: Thank you @YwH for your help, I just found out what was going on, I posted an answer to it.